# How to perform the equivalent of an index with two match criteria from excel in access

Tags: ms-access

I am moving a previously large excel file into access to help with processing speed. One of the things I did in the excel file was match a certain age and ID to a rate, using an index(,match(),match()). Ie match according to both the rows and columns of this table.

The table has the form (this is a much smaller example):

```
+====+=====+=====+======+=====+
|    | 001 | 002 | 003  | 004 |
+====+=====+=====+======+=====+
| 20 | .05 | .5  | .001 | .1  |
+----+-----+-----+------+-----+
| 21 | .1  | .6  | .005 | .44 |
+----+-----+-----+------+-----+
| 22 | .25 | .7  | .2   | .66 |
+----+-----+-----+------+-----+
| 23 | .26 | .8  | .004 | .88 |
+====+=====+=====+======+=====+
```

So say I had an entry of a age 20 year old with ID 004, this would correspond to 0.1 for example.

I have input this table into access, now I have it so that the headers are the IDs, and I'm not sure the best course of action (I'd like to avoid some form of nested if statements if possible).

Is there any way I can perform this lookup task to grab this rate from this table within a query to 'add it to the end' of a current table? Ie have some variable "Rate" that joins based on Age = 20 and ID = 004.

Thanks, and apologies if I am missing a simple method here. Not that familiar with access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field names are not values, so create a table with the fields:

```
Age    Id    Value
```

Fill with:

```
20    001    0.05
20    002    0.5
etc.
21    001    0.1
21    002    0.6
etc.
```

Now you can filter on `Age = 20 and Id = 004` and get the value of `0.1`.